# Can you both use cluster DB and non-cluster DB in AWS Database?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services

i'm very new to AWS Databases and I just have a simple question to ask.
I might not be using the correct voacbulary to so if i'm am, please let me know

What I want to know is if I use AWS database as a cluster, do all of my db need to be cluster DB?
Can I use cluster DB and non-cluster DB in my database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming of databases in Amazon RDS always confuses me too!

It seems that:

- An Amazon Aurora database is called a 'Cluster' (because it can have multiple 'DB instances')
- All other databases are called 'Database'

This should not be confused with the 'logical' database that is used *inside* the server (eg `CREATE DATABASE`). So, one database 'server' can contain multiple 'logical' databases.

Each database is separate. For example, you can have Aurora database clusters and SQL Server databases running in your account.

Comment: Now i get it about the terms and concepts of AWS databases! Thank you so much for your answer and appreciate it!